# Is there a way of deleting specific adjacent duplicates in a list on python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
my_list = ['#','#','#','@','@','@','Q','Q','#','#']
```

Expected Output:

```
[#,@,Q,Q,#]
```

Say i decided to delete all duplicates except for letter duplicates.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far

Comment: That isn't legal Python code.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: @ScottHunter Actually it is, everything after the first `#` is commented out and the close `]` could be on the next line ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: And it *could* have quotes, but didn't have that, either.

Comment: @Chris_Rands `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` >:(

Comment: Answer: Set a list of `allowed_duplicates`, then use `itertools.groupby()`: `shortened_list = [[item] if item not in allowed_duplicates else list(group) for item, group in itertools.groupby(my_str)]`. Then, flatten that list by doing `[e for sublist in shortened_list]`. Would have posted this as an answer but the question was closed before I had the chance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure:

```
excludes = ['Q']
prev = None
out = []

for item in my_list:
  if item != prev or item in excludes:
    out += item
  prev = item

print(out)
```

Comment: tagged python3, but the `print` is python2

Comment: `delete all duplicates except for letter duplicates` says the post